# How to add a text in every line with an existing texts using regex in Notepad++?

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

Is it possible to add a text or HTML tags after each line with an existing text in Notepad++?

**For example, this text:**

```
                    <p class="text-center mb-0 cfont"><a class="cfont" href="#tag">[COMPANY]</a></p>
                    Alexander Hamilton (Alexander Hamilton)
                    We are waiting in the wings for you (waiting in the wings for you)
                    You could never back down
                    You never learned to take your time!
                    Oh, Alexander Hamilton (Alexander Hamilton)
                    When America sings for you
                    Will they know what you overcame?
                    Will they know you rewrote the game?
                    The world will never be the same, oh

                    <p class="text-center mb-0 cfont"><a class="cfont" href="#tag">[BURR, MEN, & COMPANY]</a></p>
                    The ship is in the harbor now
                    See if you can spot him
                    Just you wait
                    Another immigrant
                    Comin’ up from the bottom
                    Just you wait
                    His enemies destroyed his rep
                    America forgot him
```

**The goal is to make the text above be like this: (adding the break tags)**

```
                    <p class="text-center mb-0 cfont"><a class="cfont" href="#tag">[COMPANY]</a></p>
                    Alexander Hamilton (Alexander Hamilton)</br>
                    We are waiting in the wings for you (waiting in the wings for you)</br>
                    You could never back down</br>
                    You never learned to take your time!</br>
                    Oh, Alexander Hamilton (Alexander Hamilton)</br>
                    When America sings for you</br>
                    Will they know what you overcame?</br>
                    Will they know you rewrote the game?</br>
                    The world will never be the same, oh</br>

                    <p class="text-center mb-0 cfont"><a class="cfont" href="#tag">[BURR, MEN, & COMPANY]</a></p>
                    The ship is in the harbor now</br>
                    See if you can spot him</br>
                    Just you wait</br>
                    Another immigrant</br>
                    Comin’ up from the bottom</br>
                    Just you wait</br>
                    His enemies destroyed his rep</br>
                    America forgot him</br>
```

I was using `<pre></pre>` earlier, but noticed a horizontal scroll has appeared after text wrapping and cannot make it disappear, therefore, I'm discarding it and will opt to use `<br>` tags.

The problem I have is there's no "common denominator" for each line that I can use to add the `<br>` tags. Therefore, I'm hoping there could be a regex trick to do this, like detecting an empty space after each line?

It doesn't have to be done in one go, I'm just hoping there is a quicker way to this.

A side question: Is there a a way to add an `id` or `class` to each line of these plain texts without adding `<a>` or `<p>` tags?

Lots of thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe look for `(.+)(?<!>)$` and replace with `\1</br>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$(?<=.)(?<!>)
```

Replace with `<br/>`.

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/igeAkP/1). `$(?<=.)(?<!>)` will match any end-of-line position that has a character other than line break characters before it and no `>` character afer.